# To reopen the same page with different filter

Tags: vuejs2, vue-router

In my Laravel 5/vuejs 2/ VueRouter / app I have navigation area :

```
        <li class="navigation_item_top">
            <router-link :to="{ name: 'DashboardIndex' }" class="a_link">
                Dashboard
            </router-link>
        </li>

        <li class="active navigation_item_top" >
            <a href="#backendCustomersSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">Customers</a>
            <ul class="collapse list-unstyled ml-2" id="backendCustomersSubmenu">
                <li class="mt-2">
                    <router-link :to="{name : 'listCustomers'}" class="a_link">
                        Customers
                    </router-link>
                </li>
                <li class="mt-2">
                    <router-link :to="{name : 'listCustomers', params: { filter: 'new' } }" class="a_link">
                        New Customers
                    </router-link>
                </li>
                <li class="mt-2">
                    <router-link :to="{name : 'listCustomers', params: { filter: 'inactive' } }" class="a_link">
                        Inactive Customers
                    </router-link>
                </li>
            </ul>

        </li>
```

Where there are 3 links listCustomers with different default filter opening page and it works ok if from 
DashboardIndex page I move to any listCustomers.

But it does not work if from opened listCustomers page I open listCustomers with other filter.
I suppose as VueRouter considers all listCustomers as 1 page.
If there is a way to make it and selecting other listCustomers to reopen filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if i understand your **Q** very well, but i think you want to:

1. Append query to url. e.g `company.com/listCustomers?filter=new`
2. Make Vue notice the change and do something with that change

If that's the case then try this :

```
<template>
  <--! HTML HERE -->
</template>

<script>
   export default {

      watch: {

          '$route'(to, from){

             // you don't need this but just in-case.
             //this.$forceUpdate();

             //If you're using query like ?filter=new, this should work
             if (this.$route.query.filter) {
                if (this.$route.query.filter== 'new') {

                }else{

                }
             }


           }
      }

   }
</script>
```

---

**N.B**

If you want use parameters it means you expect your `url` to be:

`domain.com/listCustomers/inactive`.

so just try the basics and link like this:

`<router-link to="/listCustomers/inactive">`

or

`<router-link to="/listCustomers/new">`.

---

And if your want queries your `url` is going to be:

`domain.com/listCustomers?filter=new`.

and you should pass exact `prop` to activate active page style.

then you need to watch for changes in the watch hook just like i did my answer

---

**Now all the been said,**

linking with parameters should work without any problem, but if you decide to use any `Navigation Guards` technique, like `router.afterEach`.
Please do not forget to add `next()`, to allow it to move on after your code. otherwise it won't navigate.

read [Navigation Guards](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#global-before-guards).

I hope you will understand.

Comment: No, having 1 page but with different filter parameter(any is separate menu item) I need somehow to reopen them with filter changing

Comment: @PetroGromovo, yes i understand that part. and i have updated my answer try it out.
it watch for any change in url query and force refresh, i hope it helps..

Comment: I have defined event : router.afterEach(( to, from ) => {
    bus.$emit('page_changed', from, to);
});
But page_changed event is not triggered in this way when I click on different menu item with the same page but different default filter. Some other way ?